# mongodb+express - mongoose not saving 'default' value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a simple form, that takes 3 string inputs. I bind these to `$scope` using `ng-model`.

What I want to be able to do, is to set a default value for the string called author in case this is left empty.

If I build my model with only `default`, an empty string gets written into my db when the field gets left empty, but when I use `require` as well, nothing gets written (db returns an error).

Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

schema:

```
var wordsSchema = new Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    default: 'unknown',
    index: true
  },
  source: String,
  quote: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  }
});
```

express API endpoint:

```
app.post('/API/addWords', function(req, res) {
    //get user from request body
    var words = req.body;

    var newWords = new Words({
        author: words.author,
        source: words.source,
        quote: words.quote
    });

    newWords.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('words saved!');
        }
    });
});
```

if you need additional info, please let me know.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`default`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) value from the schema is only used if the `author` field itself isn't present in the new doc. So you'll need to preprocess your received data to get your desired behavior using something like:

```
var words = {
    source: req.body.source,
    quote: req.body.quote
};

if (req.body.author) {
    words.author = req.body.author;
}

var newWords = new Words(words);
```

Comment: So, what should I do, If I want to load default values into the database when running app for the first time ?

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a link to that page in the docs. There doesn't seem to be a link to it anywhere else in the docs!